# What is the correct terminology for breaking up a URI into its component parts?

Tags: http, url, uri, httpclient

Suppose we have a string `"http://www.example.com/feed"`. I am breaking this string up into three pieces for use with Apache's `URI` class:
 1. "http"
 2. "www.example.com"
 3. "/feed"

Is there a proper term for this process of breaking down a URI into its component pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split or parse? I think it's really semantics, and there's not an agreed upon term.

Answer (score 6):

A uri can be parsed into it's component parts:

The following are two examples from the RFC3986:

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

A uri can be either a url or a urn.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use the  term parsing.